# Office add-in web : eligibility error with the Centralized Deployment

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I want to deploy my add-in via the centralized deployment, I add my XML file to it and then I choose the people I want them to have access to the add-in. When I validate my choice I have this error that appears:

> This operation failed. Here are the possible reasons:
>
> - Learn more about the eligibility conditions.

I looked for where the problem could come from but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance for the help !